# NHibernate - Modeling relationships between entities of the same type, with additional data

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I've pretty much exhausted Google and haven't figured out how to accomplish the mapping for my data model. More than that I haven't really figured out a great way to model the domain.

Here's the data I have:

```
CREATE TABLE Ticket (
    Id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Name nvarchar(250) NULL
    -- And a lot of other columns
)
```

Now each Ticket can have any number of related tickets, but the key is that this relationship is a peer relationship, not a parent-child. Here's the association table:

```
CREATE TABLE TicketRelationship (
    TicketA_Id int NOT NULL,
    TicketB_Id int NOT NULL,
    Description nvarchar(max) NULL
)
```

The idea here is that when viewing a Ticket with other related tickets, I'll be able to view not only the related tickets but the description of that relationship. And I'll be able to see that whether I'm looking at Ticket A or Ticket B.

The problem is how to 1) model this in my domain in such a way that doesn't create two `TicketRelationship` records for each two-way relationship, and 2) how to map that domain model with NHibernate (I'm using Fluent NH).

Ideally, this is how the ticket class would work out:

```
public class Ticket : EntityBase<Ticket>, IAggregateRoot
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IDictionary<Ticket, string> RelatedTickets { get; set; }
}
```

Where the string in the `IDictionary` is the `Description` column in the relationship table.

The challenge now is how to map this such that the related ticket shows up in the list regardless of whether it's referenced in the `TicketA_Id` or `TicketB_id` columns.

If this is not possible, then I could split the domain model such that the class appears like this:

```
public class Ticket : EntityBase<Ticket>, IAggregateRoot
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IDictionary<Ticket, string> ReferencesTickets { get; set; }
    public virtual IDictionary<Ticket, string> ReferencedByTickets { get; set; }
}
```

This might simplify things a bit, but with a single association table I haven't been able to get the mappings to work. I tried this, but FNH doesn't let me specify the parent and child key columns:

```
        mapping.HasMany(x => x.ReferencesTickets)
            .Table("TicketRelationships")
            .AsEntityMap()
            .KeyColumn("TicketA_Id")
            .Element("Description");
        
        mapping.HasMany(x => x.ReferencedByTickets)
            .Table("TicketRelationships")
            .AsEntityMap()
            .KeyColumn("TicketB_Id")
            .Element("Description");
```

Any ideas how I can make this work?

### Update:

I was able to get the fallback scenario to work by adjusting the mappings to this:

```
        mapping.HasMany(x => x.ReferencesTickets)
            .Table("TicketRelationships")
            .AsEntityMap("TicketB_Id")
            .KeyColumn("TicketA_Id")
            .Element("Description");
        
        mapping.HasMany(x => x.ReferencedByTickets)
            .Table("TicketRelationships")
            .AsEntityMap("TicketA_Id")
            .KeyColumn("TicketB_Id")
            .Element("Description");
```

However, if there's a way to have a single `IDictionary` to simplify it I'd love to hear any suggestions.

Comment: i would stick with two dictionaries, because they are different associations of one Ticket